# Can GNU Octave run simulink model?

Tags: matlab, octave, simulink

From what I understand, GNU Octave can run functions in .m files. Can it run simulink models too?

For example, doing this in an m file:

```
rv = sim('simulink_model.slx');
rv.Output.Data
```

And perhaps call this from Octave? I'm unable to try this myself because I don't have simulink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not natively. You would need to use Scilab xcos and the Sci cosim Octave toolbox to communicate with it from Octave (see the [docs](http://wiki.octave.org/Sci_cosim)) or run it directly from Scilab.

Even then I believe you'd need to re-write your Simulink models, one comparison can be found here:

http://x-engineer.org/xcos-vs-simulink-continuous-time

And the official xcos docs can be found here:

https://www.scilab.org/software/xcos